# Se que fallo en algo, pero en qué?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Puede que mi pregunta esté ya formulada pero no la encuentro, tengo el siguiente código:

```
//  Devuelvo los datos recibidos como JSON y los proceso...
function cargarUsuarios() {
  //  Conexion a bbdd y queries
  httpRequest("php/users.php", function(){
    const arreglo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    const conectados = arreglo.connected;
    const desconectados = arreglo.disconnected;
    const pendientes = arreglo.pending;
    //  Para los usuarios conectados
    if(conectados.length > 0){
      conectados.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user)
      });
    }
  });
}
//  Cada 200ms pregunto al servidor por si hay cambios en los datos
setInterval(() => {
  cargarUsuarios();
}, 200)
```

El funcionamiento es el siguiente:

1. Realizo una petición AJAX a mi servidor cada 200ms y me devuelve los usuarios que esten conectados en formato JSON.
2. Proceso los datos (Quiero pintarlos pero de momento estoy con el console)

Lo que deseo es cuando pregunto al servidor, si los datos son iguales a los que ya tenía no modificar nada ni pintar ni nada, en cambio cuando se reciban modificaciones a las que actualmente se tienen, pues refrescar los datos pintados.

El output que me sale es el Array de objetos recibido pero por siempre (Supongamos que tengo 2 usuarios conectados, con sus datos, pues sale ese/esos mismos datos una y otra vez). Adjunto output

```js
let arreglo = {
  "connected": [{
    "user_name": "ramoncin",
    "first_name": "Ramon",
    "last_name": null,
    "first_surname": "Pirez",
    "last_surname": null,
    "img": "ramon2009.png",
    "user_status": 1
  }],
  "disconnected": [{
    "user_name": "test",
    "first_name": "Test",
    "last_name": null,
    "first_surname": "Final",
    "last_surname": null,
    "img": "test.png",
    "user_status": 0
  }],
  "pending": ["admin"]
}

//  Devuelvo los datos recibidos como JSON y los proceso...
function cargarUsuarios() {
  //  Conexion a bbdd y queries (El objeto anterior emula este proceso
  /*
  httpRequest("php/users.php", function(){
    const arreglo = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    const conectados = arreglo.connected;
    const desconectados = arreglo.disconnected;
    const pendientes = arreglo.pending;
    //  Para los usuarios conectados
    if(conectados.length > 0){
      conectados.forEach(user => {
        console.log(user)
      });
    }
  });
  */
  const conectados = arreglo.connected;
  const desconectados = arreglo.disconnected;
  const pendientes = arreglo.pending;
  //  Para los usuarios conectados
  if (conectados.length > 0) {
    conectados.forEach(user => {
      console.log(user)
    });
  }
}
//  Cada 200ms pregunto al servidor por si hay cambios en los datos
setInterval(() => {
  cargarUsuarios();
}, 200)
```

**PD: El código lo estoy haciendo en VanillaJS**

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que expliques de mejor manera tu pregunta, por ejemplo el título actual no describe en nada el problema expuesto, además en la pregunta solo se aprecia un código pero no describes que fallo obtienes

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Fallas en que no explicas cuál es el problema ni explicas cuál es el resultado de tus depuraciones ni explicas qué es lo que quieres hacer. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: ahora edito !! @A.Cedano

Comment: @BetaM creo que ya está

Comment: El *quid* de la cuestión está aquí: *Lo que deseo es cuando pregunto al servidor, si los datos son iguales a los que ya tenía no modificar nada ni pintar ni nada, en cambio cuando se reciban modificaciones a las que actualmente se tienen, pues refrescar los datos pintados.* Pregunto: ¿tienes pensada alguna manera de determinar esto fácilmente o hay que comparar cada vez los datos para ver si son distintos o no? No valdría por ejemplo contar, porque puede haber entrado un usuario y salido otro, habría misma cantidad de usuarios, pero distintas personas.

Comment: Una forma fácil sería poner en el objeto **la última fecha/hora**  en que fueron actualizados los datos (en el servidor) y comparar contra ese valor. Creo que para una respuesta óptima a lo que preguntas falta contexto.

Comment: @A.Cedano No porque a lo que pongo énfasis es a si el usuario está conectado. Cada vez que pregunto quiero confirmar los usuarios que están conectados, si de repente uno se desconecta ahi si que se reflejen esos cambios. No sabría exactamente como explicarlo de una manera mas técnica.

Comment: Tienes que saber explicarlo si quieres que entendamos el problema. A veces el problema es no saber explicar el problema. Explicándolo encuentras muchas veces la solución o te das cuenta de que el problema es que estás aplicando una lógica equivocada.

Comment: @A.Cedano Tienes razón, a ver si en principio yo quiero recibir una lista de usuarios, esa lista la recibo bien y hasta ahí todo perfecto. Se pinta, pero una vez que la haya recibido y pintado, para no consumir tantos recursos, deseo que cuando ya una vez recibidos los datos, si hay modificaciones en los datos nuevos que siguen llegando, actualizar los datos que he pintado. Es decir, recibo datos, no se si tengo que guardarlos en una nueva variable o que pero, una vez los tengo recibidos comparo con los que me van llegando, si no son iguales pues actualizo, si son iguales no hago nada. Creo...

Comment: @A.Cedano no tengo mal la lógica aplicada y el código hasta cierto punto hace lo que quiero pero ya te digo, me saca todo el rato los mismos usuarios, y es difiicl mostrarte a tiempo real porque lo tengo alojado en un servidor local, en una base de datos local con archivos php locales.

Comment: Podrías tener dos llamadas, una para ejecutar al cargar, donde te devuelva todos los usuarios y una marca temporal (fecha y hora). Otra para actualizar, donde te devuelva los cambios a partir de la marca y, por supuesto, también te devuelva una nueva marca. Creo que esto te facilitaría la lógica y ayudaría a optimizar recursos.

Comment: Imagino que los usuarios conectados se guardan en alguna tabla en tu base de datos. Pues yo lo resolvería así. Tendría una tabla con una sola columna y una sola fila llamada por ejemplo `last_connection` que sería una marca del tiempo (TIMESTAMP). Pues bien, cada vez que un usuario se conecta (o desconecta) actualizaría esa tabla mediante un TRIGGER y luego verificaría desde el cliente  si el último TIMESTAMP que tengo en el cliente es el mismo que hay en la tabla del servidor, así sabrás si desde la última vez hubo cambios o no. Es una lógica que se aproxima más o menos a ...

Comment: ... una solución óptima, pero puede que haga falta refinarla. Por ejemplo, si necesitas saber por cada usuario lo que ha ocurrido (si se conectó o desconectó) para desdibujarlo de tu contenedor en el cliente, necesitarás tener quizá un registro por el id del usuario y un estatus que puede ser numérico, como `0` para desconectado, `1` para conectado, etc. Hay mil formas de resolver esto, pero la cuestión más delicada aquí es poder tener un control sin tener que estar trayendo cada vez todos los datos del servidor y comparándolos con todos los datos del cliente.